# Kernel definition. What space is the resulting 0 vector in?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading this text about the kernel:

[image]

So I think I get this:

> V → W, the zero vector in V maps to the zero vector in W. That is, T(0) = 0. The first question you will consider in this section is whether there are other vectors v such that T(v) = 0. The collection of all such elements is called the kernel of T.

So say the initial 0 vector is [0,0] in space R^n and we're trying to map it to the 0 vector in R^3. There will be some transformation that maps the [0,0] to [0,0,0] right? So in this one, is the kernel just [0,0]?

I'm having trouble understanding example 2, the kernels of the zero and identity transformation. What does $ker(T) = V$ mean?

This is too abstract for me to get. Can someone clarify this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So say the initial 0 vector is [0,0] in space R^n and we're trying to map it to the 0 vector in R^3. There will be some transformation that maps the [0,0] to [0,0,0] right?

Yes. But note that *any* linear transformation from ${\bf R}^2$ to ${\bf R}^3$ would map $[0,0]$ to $[0,0,0]$.

> So in this one, is the kernel just [0,0]?

No. Consider the zero transformation $T:{\bf R}^2\to{\bf R}^3$ where $T([x,y])=[0,0,0]$. You have
$$
T([0,0])=[0,0,0]
$$
but
$$
\ker T = {\bf R}^2,
$$
since $T$ maps everything in ${\bf R}^2$ to $[0,0,0]$.

In example 2, the notation $\ker(T)=V$ is an identity of sets. It means $\ker(T)$ and $V$ are two *same* sets: every element in $\ker T$ is an element in $V$ and every element in $V$ is an element in $\ker(T)$.

Comment: ohhh it’s saying that if there’s a zero transformation (we don’t know it yet) but we do know it takes a vector and transforms it to 0 vector (in space W) so by default all of v in V fits into the kernel right?

Comment: "if there’s a zero transformation(we don’t know it yet)"  We know *the* zero transformation is always there. By **definition**, it maps everything in the domain to a zero vector. And yes, in the case of the zero transformation $T$, every element in the domain (V) is in the kernel of $T$.